# Symbian development with Qt e32std.h not found

Tags: qt, cmake, symbian

I am trying to compile a cmake project for symbian using QtSDK (Qt 4.7). 
When I build it within the Qt Creator, I get these errors:

```
C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/include/QtCore/qatomic_symbian.h:46: error: e32std.h:  
No such file or directory

C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/include/QtCore/qatomic_symbian.h: In member
function 'bool QBasicAtomicInt::ref()':

C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/include/QtCore/qatomic_symbian.h:135: error: 'User' 
has not been declared

C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/include/QtCore/qatomic_symbian.h:135: error: 'TInt' was not declared in this scope

C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/include/QtCore/qatomic_symbian.h:135: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/include/QtCore/qatomic_symbian.h: In member function 'bool QBasicAtomicInt::deref()':

C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/include/QtCore/qatomic_symbian.h:141: error: 'User' has not been declared

C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/include/QtCore/qatomic_symbian.h:141: error: 'TInt' was not declared in this scope

C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/include/QtCore/qatomic_symbian.h:141: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
```

I have checked that e32std.h exists at C:\QtSDK\Symbian\SDKs\Symbian3Qt473\epoc32\include
But still these errors occur.

It seems to me that cmake is not able to find the correct architecture for compilation.
I am using cmake for windows.

What could be the problem ?